# Masonry infinite scrolling (by appending partial)? [Rails]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll, jquery-masonry, masonry

So I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling into Masonry by appending a rendered partial, as opposed to appending a div. Appending a div -- that's exactly how the [Infinite Scroll jQuery plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/) by Paul Irish works. I used to use it but now it's of no use to me as I want to append partials instead. You're probably confused but I'll try to clear the confusion with the codes:

**masonry.js**

```
var $container = $('.postindex');

  $container.imagesLoaded(function (){

    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.posts-wrapper',
      isFitWidth: true,
      percentPosition: true
    });
  });
```

**pagination.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  if ($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      var more_posts_url;
      more_posts_url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');
      if (more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
        $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..."/>');
        $.getScript(more_posts_url);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

**index.html.haml**

```
.postindex.transitions-enabled.infinite-scroll.page
  .postin
    -@posts.each do |post|
      = render 'posts/post', post: post
#infinite-scrolling
  = will_paginate @posts
```

**_post.html.haml** (extract)

```
.posts-wrapper
  .post
    .image.center-block
      %a{id: "imageurl_#{post.id}", href: "/", "data-gallery": ""}
        = cl_image_tag(post.image.full_public_id, quality:"auto", fetch_format:"auto", width:640, crop: "scale", class: "img-responsive")
```

So, in this case, instead of appending `posts-wrapper` div, I want to append the entire `post` partial. This is exactly how the infinite scroll code was written before I implemented Masonry:

**index.js.erb**

```
$('.postin').append('<%= j render @posts %>');
<% if @posts.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @posts %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

This of course doesn't work with Masonry (the appended items overlap the existing ones). Now how do I get this to work?

---

In case you're wondering why I need to append a partial instead of a div, I have a piece of script at the end of `_post.html.haml` that I need to make sure runs every time a post is loaded. Here's the full file:

**_post.html.haml** (full)

```
.posts-wrapper
  .post
    .image.center-block
      %a{id: "imageurl_#{post.id}", href: "/", "data-gallery": ""}
        = cl_image_tag(post.image.full_public_id, quality:"auto", fetch_format:"auto", width:640, crop: "scale", class: "img-responsive")


:javascript
  if ($(window).width() <= 800){
    $("#imageurl_#{post.id}").attr("href", '#{escape_javascript( render :partial => 'posts/imageurl800', :locals => {:post => post })}');
  }
  else if ($(window).width() <= 1200) {
    $("#imageurl_#{post.id}").attr("href", '#{escape_javascript( render :partial => 'posts/imageurl1200', :locals => {:post => post })}');
  }
  else if ($(window).width() <= 1600) {
    $("#imageurl_#{post.id}").attr("href", '#{escape_javascript( render :partial => 'posts/imageurl1600', :locals => {:post => post })}');  
  }
  else {
    $("#imageurl_#{post.id}").attr("href", '#{escape_javascript( render :partial => 'posts/imageurl1920', :locals => {:post => post })}');
  }
```

where `_imageurl800.html.haml` is:

```
= cl_image_path(post.image.full_public_id, width:800, crop:"scale", class:"img-responsive")
```

and `_imageurl1200.html.haml` is:

```
= cl_image_path(post.image.full_public_id, width:1200, crop:"scale", class:"img-responsive")
```

and so on.

Basically what it's doing is, every time a post is loaded, it checks the width of the browser, and depending on that it loads the image in the gallery (`"data-gallery": ""`) in a particular size when clicked on. I hope I'm clear. If there's a better way to tackle the entire thing then please suggest so. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, several hours later...

```
var $postbox = $('<%= j render @posts %>');
var $container = $('.postindex');

$postbox.imagesLoaded(function (){
$container.append.($postbox).masonry('appended', $postbox);    
});

<% if @posts.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @posts %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a DRY-er approach and it solved my problem. I removed the script from the partial and instead made a js function to search and replace text in the URL. So for instance:

**_post.html.haml**

```
%a{class: "post_url", href: "#{cl_image_path(post.image.full_public_id, width:640, crop:"scale", class:"img-responsive")}", "data-gallery": ""}
```

**masonry.js**

```
function urlhelper() {
  $("a.post_url").each(function(){
    var str = $(this).attr('href')
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
      var txt = str.replace("w_640","w_800");
    } else if ($(window).width() <= 1200) {
      var txt = str.replace("w_640","w_1200");
    } else if ($(window).width() <= 1600) {
      var txt = str.replace("w_640","w_1600");
    } else {
      var txt = str.replace("w_640","w_1920");
    }
    $(this).attr('href', txt);
  });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  urlhelper();
});

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  urlhelper();
});
```

This solves my problem, but I still would like to know if it's possible to add infinite scrolling to masonry by rendering partials. So if you know the answer to that, don't hesitate to let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended

> While jQuery can add an HTML string with .append(), Masonry's appended cannot. When adding content with jQuery ajax methods like $.get() or $.ajax(), wrap HTML content string in a jQuery object to use it with appended.

```
// does not work
$.get( 'page2', function( content ) {
  // HTML string added, but items not added to Masonry
  $grid.append( content ).masonry( 'appended', content );
});

// does work
$.get( 'page2', function( content ) {
  // wrap content in jQuery object
  var $content = $( content );
  // add jQuery object
  $grid.append( $content ).masonry( 'appended', $content );
});
```